# OData Source Error: "Cannot acquire a managed connection from the run-time connection manager" after deploying on a server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sharepoint, ssis, odata

OData Source Error: "Cannot acquire a managed connection from the run-time connection manager".
The error shows up when I deploy the package on the server. It works just fine when I execute the package in Visual Studio.

On the same server I have another SSIS package that uses OData to connect to SharePoint Online. And that works just fine.

I have checked that the SharePoint client component installed on the server is same as the one on my machine. The .NET framework on the server is identical to mine.

Have been looking at other similar questions posted but has not helped solve this issue. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: On the same server I have another SSIS package that uses OData to connect to SharePoint Online. And that works just fine.